# Extending fibre metrics of submanifolds to Riemannian metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $S\subseteq M$ a properly embedded smooth submanifold. Suppose that we have a fibre metric on $TM|_S$, i.e. a positive definite real inner-product on $T_pM$ for all $p\in S$, which depends smoothly on $p\in S$. Can it always be extended to a Riemannian metric on $TM$?

Comment: Yes. Use bump functions to reduce to the case of $S$ a linear subspace of a vector space $M$.